# whats the fastest way possible to copy a directory like Desktop,documents to another directory in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

so i already wrote it below here but it isn't fast enough it takes 10 minutes to copy 60mb to another folder is there a more efficient way to do it.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
system("mkdir copies");

std::filesystem::copy("C:\\Users\\tayie\\OneDrive\\Pictures", "D:\\Copies\\copied_photos");
std::filesystem::copy("C:\\Users\\tayie\\OneDrive\\Documents","D:\\Copies\\copied_documents");
std::filesystem::copy("C:\\Users\\tayie\\OneDrive\\Desktop", "D:\\Copies\\copied_desktop");
}
```

but the code runs really slow for how little the size of the dir are is there anyway to make it run faster, any help would be greatly appreciate, thank you.

Comment: What kind of drive do you have (HDD/SSD/etc)? Are both partitions on the same drive?

Comment: It's most likely slow because of using the cloud drive as the source. You could be waiting to download from the internet.

Comment: @drescherjm is OneDrive directory actually special in some way? I always thought it's a regular directory, it's just OneDrive app synchronizing it from time to time.

Comment: ***is OneDrive directory actually special in some way?*** Files that appear the directory may not be available on the local system. If they aren't it will have to download them before the copy happens. The icon in explorer should show you if they are local or cloud only. You can control where they are by pinning: [https://www.theexperienceblog.com/2017/09/26/use-attrib-to-pin-and-unpin-files-and-folders-for-onedrive-on-demand-sync-in-windows-10/](https://www.theexperienceblog.com/2017/09/26/use-attrib-to-pin-and-unpin-files-and-folders-for-onedrive-on-demand-sync-in-windows-10/)

Comment: I have an 25TB onedrive account with 5 to 10TB used at work.

Comment: @drescherjm is there a way to disable it from getting files from onedrive??

Comment: You can use the link I added above to pin the files to your local folder to make sure the file is always available on your local storage. `attrib +p -u Document2.docx` will make `Document2.docx` always available locally.

Comment: yes but is there a way to change it in the code above so it only copies locally stored files and ignore the onedrive ones??

Comment: You would have to iterate through each file checking the attributes to tell if it is available offline or cloud only. The iteration part you can do using the c++ filesystem library the rest will need to look at windows api functions.